# How can I do a global Model afterSave() on Cake?

Tags: cakephp, after-save

How can I do a global Model afterSave() on Cake? I want to do some things right after a save is done.

Thanks,
Gino

Answer (score 4):

Put it in your AppModel (and extend your models from that). Check out [the CookBook on models](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1001/Understanding-Models)